# Is it possible to specify the order in which Yosemite (Barracuda) backup backs up servers?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, barracuda

We have a server that backs up a number of other servers directly to tape using Barracuda Yosemite Server Backup. To save time, we would like to move the start time back by a couple of hours, however this could cause problems if the backup of a particular server starts too early. Is there any way to ensure that the servers get backed up in a specific order (or at least to specify that one particular server should be the last one to be backed up)?

We are using Yosemite Server Backup 10.3